# Read only transaction table locking

Tags: database, hibernate, jpa, locking

I'm using JPA 2.0, Hibernate and MySQL. The isolation of MySQL db is TRANSACTION_REPEATABLE_READ. I have a set of queries which will be used for displaying data on the website. Some of those queries will have to fetch a lot of rows and they can be modified in the middle by some other process. Do I have to use any kind of locking (pessimistic or optimistic) for those read only queries to make sure that the result set will be consistent?

Does using optimistic locking with auto object versioning via @Version annotation make any sense for read only queries?

**I'm not sure why would ever anybody have to explicitly specify LockModeType.OPTIMISTIC on entity or query. If the object is versioned it will be checked on commit anyway, right?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you put your selects in a transaction, the TRANSACTION_REPEATABLE_READ isolation level will prevent the selected rows to be updated until your select transaction commits. But will not prevent inserts.

This is a pessimistic locking approach which is appropriate for your use case. I assume that your select transaction is short living because the clients trying to update some of the selected rows are waiting for the select transaction to commit.

The optimistic locking strategy with versioning is more useful in a "modify record" use case when some client selects a row, spends 2,3 or 10 minutes looking/modifying the record(in a user interface) and then saves(commits) its modifications. With this strategy we don't want other clients to wait for the first one to save its modifications.